# integral that used to calculate total energy that reaches a planet

Tags: integration

How should I solve this integral $?$.

- This integral is used to calculate the total energy that reaches a planet.
- Most of the time, we ignore the parentheses after $D$, because it doesn't make much difference, but if we don't do this, we get to this integral.

How to solve it $?$.

$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{{\rm d}\varphi\,{\rm d}\theta}
{\left\{D + R\left[1-\cos\left(\varphi\right)
\cos\left(\theta\right )\right]\right\}^{\,2}}
$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What is $D$?  I don't see one

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry i fixed it

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you mean by ignoring "the parentheses after $D$". Do you mean the term $R\cdot \left(1-\ldots \right)$?

Comment: @Jam Yes, R is the radius of the planet. When R is too small compared to D (the distance from the planet to the star), we ignore the R(1-...) part.

Comment: May you show your attempt so we can help?

Comment: It looks like Elliptic Functions are involved.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{\cal P} & \equiv \color{#44f}{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}
{\dd\varphi\,\dd\theta \over 
{\braces{D +
R\bracks{1-\cos\pars{\varphi}\cos\pars{\theta}}}^{\,2}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{4 \over \pars{D + R}^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\dd\varphi\,\dd\theta \over 
{\bracks{1
-\epsilon\cos\pars{\varphi}\cos\pars{\theta}}^{\,2}}}\right\vert_{\epsilon\ \equiv\ R/\pars{D + R}}
\\[5mm] & =
{4 \over \pars{D + R}^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left\{
{4\root{2}\on{arctanh}\pars{\root{2}\bracks{1 + \epsilon\cos\pars{\varphi}}}/\root{\epsilon^{2}\cos\pars{2\varphi} + \epsilon^{2} - 2}} \over \bracks{\epsilon^{2}\cos\pars{2\varphi} + \epsilon^{2} - 2}^{3/2}\right.
\\ & \left.\phantom{{4 \over \pars{D + r}^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\hspace{1.2cm}}- {2\epsilon\cos\pars{\varphi} \over \epsilon^{2}\cos\pars{2\varphi} + \epsilon^{2} - 2}\right\}\dd\varphi
\end{align}
The last expression is the $\ds{\tt Mathematica}$ result after integrating over $\ds{\theta}$. I $\ds{\underline{\rm don't}}$ expect a further refinement.

However, maybe a useful answer can be found, when
$\ds{0 < \epsilon << 1}$, by expanding $\ds{\bracks{1
-\epsilon\cos\pars{\varphi}\cos\pars{\theta}}^{\,-2}\ }$ in powers of $\ds{\epsilon}$. Namely,
$$
{\cal P}\hspace{5mm} \sr{{\rm as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\hspace{5mm}
{\pi^{2} + 8\epsilon + \pars{3\pi^{2}/4}\epsilon^{2} + \pars{64/9}\epsilon^{3} \over \pars{D + R}^{2}}
$$